Why mapstruct setting all values to null in the new arraylist
I am trying to create a list by using the fields in two object using map struct. Its creating the new list successfully with all the fields but i am losing all the values in the objects. I am using map struct 1.5.5 Final and not using lombok for getter and setter. Please help me to find out what i am missing.
public static void main(String[] args) {
 FhExtra fhExtra = new FhExtra();
 fhExtra.setLoanNumber("123456");
 fhExtra.setFILoanNumber("896");
 FhExtraImportResults extraImportResults1 = new FhExtraImportResults();
 extraImportResults1.setLoanId(56L);
 extraImportResults1.setRecord(fhExtra);
 List<FhExtraImportResults> extraImportResults = new ArrayList<>();
 extraImportResults.add(extraImportResults1);

 FhListItemMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(FhListItemMapper.class);
 List<FhlbExtraCsv> newList = extraImportResults.stream().map(mapper::map).toList();
 // newList  is having all the fields but dont have the values i set.
 }



 @Mapper
 public interface FhListItemMapper {
 @Mapping(target = "loanId", source = "results.loanId")
 @Mapping(target = "error", source = "results.error")
 FhlbExtraCsv map(FhlbExtraImportResults results);
 }


 public class FhExtra {
 String LoanNumber;
 String FILoanNumber;
 }

 public class FhlbExtraImportResults {
 FhExtra record;
 String error;
 Long loanId;
 }

 public class FhlbExtraCsv {
 String LoanNumber;
 String FILoanNumber;
 String error;
 Long loanId;
 }

Expected output is like
[{
 LoanNumber : 123456
 FILoanNumber : 896
 error : null
 loanId : 56
}]


In your case, since the variable names in the target object can't be directly matched up with with variables from the source object nested object, you're going to have to define those mappings too, like so:
public interface FhListItemMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "FILoanNumber", source= "results.record.FILoanNumber")
    @Mapping(target = "LoanNumber", source = "results.record.LoanNumber")
    @Mapping(target = "loanId", source = "results.loanId")
    @Mapping(target = "error", source = "results.error")
    Main.FhlbExtraCsv map(Main.FhExtraImportResults results);
}

Also, I don't know what you need this code for, but please look into JLS and try to include the code as-is, because it took a while to make this code compile, so I wouldn't know if you have other issues with it.
EDIT:

Thanks for the response , But i am trying to find out a way to avoid
explicit mapping .

In that case, you can modify the code so that all the variables you'd want to implicitly map are in the root source objects (you can have multiple source objects) like so
@Mapper
public interface FhListItemMapper {
    Main.FhlbExtraCsv map(Main.FhExtraImportResults results, Main.FhExtra extra);
}

In this case however, you'd also need to make a small change in the stream mapping too, from method reference, to a lambda:
        List<FhlbExtraCsv> newList = extraImportResults.stream().map(ir->mapper.map(ir, ir.record)).collect(Collectors.toList());


Thanks for the response , But i am trying to find out a way to avoid explicit mapping .
